# Converting object to array of objects after GET from CouchDB in an Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the code below, I'd like the $scope.persons variable to consist of an array of objects that I GET from CouchDB.

```
.controller('personsCtrl', ['$scope', 'personSrv', function personsCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.persons = function(){
      return $http.get('http://localhost:5984/quotes/_all_docs?include_docs=true')
          .then(function(response) {
              if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                  return $.map(response.data, function(el){return el});
              } else {
                  // invalid response
                  return $q.reject(response.data);
              }

          }, function(response) {
              // something went wrong
              return $q.reject(response.data);
          });
    }
}])
```

So that I can display the information on my page like this:

```
<div>
    <p class="lead">Persons</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="p in persons"><a ng-href="#/quotes/{{ p.doc.dataid }}">{{ p.doc.dataname }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Each object/person has an id, a name and a quote. I tried using $.map to convert the data I got from the GET to an array, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: What is the markup between the objects to separate them? Because if the returns is only one object, you can simple `$scope.persons.push(response.data)`

Comment: Is the object that is returned  on the promise an array nested within an object literal or where you saying that it's an array with multiple object literals? What does the data structure look like that is in response.data?

Comment: I'm not quite sure; I used to be able to use data.rows to convert the data I got back from a GET call to an array. I suppose it returns the documents from CouchDB as a JSON object.